# Does Using GOTO in Windows7 Batch Files skip code and go back to the next line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im getting misinformation from different sites and perhaps its a Windows/DOS version reason for the disparity.

If I script something like this:

```
echo line 1
goto TEST
echo line 2
goto EOF

:TEST 
echo line 3

:EOF
```

> Is it suppose to print out "line 1" then goto TEST print "line 3" then
>   goto EOF
>
> or  Is it suppose to print out "line 1" then goto TEST print
>   "line 3" then return to the calling goto (TEST) and print line 2 then
>   goto EOF

Just looking for clarification on GOTO / CALL actually works whether it is meant to SKIP code or be more like a method/function where it calls it that continues from where it was called.

Comment: Not a good idea to make your own label `:eof`. `call :label` will execute an internal subroutine (starting at the label `:label` in the current batch file.) `call label` (without the colon) will execute an executable (typically a batchfile) named `label`. `goto :eof` is very specific - go to the end-of-file (which terminates the batch or subroutine). Whereas `goto label` and `goto :label` are identical for any other label, if you use your own `:eof` label, `goto :eof` and `goto eof` work differently. Hence this author eschews the `goto :label` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Goto` will simply cause the script to continue running from the label you point it at. You can use the `Call` command instead.

```
echo line 1
call TEST
echo line 2
goto EOF

:TEST 
echo line 3

:EOF
```

This will echo `line 1` then call `:TEST` which will echo `line 3` then hit `:EOF` and return to the call. The script will then echo `line 2` and goto `:EOF`. The call command will treat the script after the label as a kind of sub script, requiring an exit, in this case it hits `:EOF`.

You can give the call command 'help' a read -

```
C:\>call /?
Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

  batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required by the
                     batch program.

If Command Extensions are enabled CALL changes as follows:

CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL.  The syntax
is:

    CALL :label arguments

A new batch file context is created with the specified arguments and
control is passed to the statement after the label specified.  You must
"exit" twice by reaching the end of the batch script file twice.  The
first time you read the end, control will return to just after the CALL
statement.  The second time will exit the batch script.  Type GOTO /?
for a description of the GOTO :EOF extension that will allow you to
"return" from a batch script.

In addition, expansion of batch script argument references (%0, %1,
etc.) have been changed as follows:
```

Answer (score 3):

The former of your suggestions is correct, it is supposed to print out "line 1" then goto TEST print "line 3" then goto EOF.

Lines 3 and 4 will always be skipped. DOS Batch files are linear - That is, they run line by line. You could of course make a line after :TEST goto :SOMEOTHERPLACE